# phpmyadmin in docker console errors

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, phpmyadmin, reverse-proxy

I have three servers - mysql(3306 on localhost) nginx(80 443 ports) and phpmyadmin (5000) in same docker network. When i'm trying get access to phpmyadmin on localhost:5000 - its working perfect [phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqP7H.png)

But when i'm used reverse-proxy on my nginx server with code:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass https://${PMA}:5000/;
}
```

I got white screen and console.log errors:

```
phpmyadmin:21 GET https://localhost/js/whitelist.php?v=5.0.4 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
phpmyadmin:15 GET https://localhost/js/vendor/codemirror/addon/lint/lint.css?v=5.0.4 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
phpmyadmin:14 GET https://localhost/js/vendor/codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css?v=5.0.4 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
phpmyadmin:25 GET https://localhost/js/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js?v=5.0.4
```

..
How i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that nginx and phpmyadmin are on serving docker. I use below configuration, you can change 172.17.0.1 with containers docker network gateway IP.

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:5000;
}
```

If there is a firewall, you must check the firewall configurations that are allowed to access docker containers each other.

iptables rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 172.17.0.1/16 -j ACCEPT
```

firewall-cmd rule:

```
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=172.17.0.1/16 accept' --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: Thank's i try check filewall, but it's look like nginx container searching files inside itself. ${PMA}  replacing on IP address with command = envsubst < nginx.template.conf > nginx.conf

Comment: have you tried to adding phpmyadmin docker environment variable PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI=http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Comment: tried, new error log:
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
jquery.min.js?v=5.0.4:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
jquery-migrate.js?v=5.0.4:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
whitelist.php?v=5.0.4:1